# How do i Bulk delete a specific channel?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I just want to know how i can bulk delete only one channel and ignore the rest of the channels whenever someone tries to use the bulk delete command in a different channel.

Comment: It's not a bulk delete if it's just one channel, how do you know which channel to delete, is there a second paramater that tells the name or does it delete a random channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call [`bulkDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextBasedChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) on the channel that you want to bulk delete.

For example, this code can be used to make `!bulkdelete #channel` (mentioning the channel) bulk delete the messages in `#channel`:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!bulkdelete') {
    const channel = message.mentions.channels.first()
    // you can also bulk delete a news (announcement) channel so if you need to cater for
    // those use if (channel.type !== 'text' && channel.type !== 'news')
    if (channel.type !== 'text') {
      // you can't bulk delete a voice (or store) channel
      return
    }
    channel.bulkDelete()
  }
})
```